# Check if a database table has been renamed

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My app has a list of an external db's tables and it needs to be regularly updated. How do I check if a table has been renamed? i.e. how to differentiate between a new table and an old table that's been renamed? Looking for sql/python/sqlalchemy solutions that'll work in as many engines as possible.

I'm aware of [OID in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625585/sql-postgres-oids-what-are-they-and-why-are-they-useful) but as far as I could tell it isn't very reliable and there's no equivalent in mysql. I suppose I could do something with the create time and modify time but I'm trying to see if there's an easier way.

Edit: The app is a data visualisation tool to which external dbs connect. I do not have control over the design of dbs that connect to the app which is why I need to account for tables getting renamed.

Comment: It may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693448/sql-server-find-out-when-a-table-was-renamed

Comment: If renaming tables is an issue in your project then you might want to stop doing that or at least reduce it to the absolute minimum.

Comment: Renaming tables is an absolute no can do! Looks like your database design is broken.

Comment: Like I said it's for external dbs i.e. client dbs. I  do not do the design, my app simply connect to their db to visualise the data. I need to cover all bases.

Comment: If your tables are getting renamed an your app isn't being shut down and restarted during the migration you're living pretty dangerously. Usually migrations that alter *anything* are closely coordinated so the various systems hanging off that database can be notified and updated accordingly in sync.

Comment: The db in question is not the application's db. It's a source db from which insights are extracted and used to populate the app's db. It's a visualisation app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to establish the identity of a database table in PostgreSQL than through the OID (system column `tableoid`). Creation time is not stored in PostgreSQL.

Relying on the table OID is not only proprietary to PostgreSQL, but also somewhat unsafe, since OIDs can get reused. I recommend that you keep an inventory of your table modifications in a separate database table.